# R: sapply (or other *apply functions) with different argument each time

Tags: r

Let's say I have the following list:

```
X <- list(1:5, 1:5, 1:5, 1:5)
```

I want to use `sapply` on `X` with `FUN = sample` but with different arguments for `FUN` each time. For instance: `size = c(2, 3, 3, 2)`.

The expected output should look like this:

```
[[1]]
[1] 5 3        # sample(X[[1]], size = 2)

[[2]]
[1] 5 4 1      # sample(X[[2]], size = 3)

[[3]]
[1] 2 5 4      # sample(X[[3]], size = 3)

[[4]]
[1] 4 2        # sample(X[[4]], size = 2)
```

I would rather avoid for loops if possible.

Comment: `mapply(sample, X, size)`?

Comment: @nrussell Thank you! I wasn't aware of `mapply`